# How to consume own library in asp.net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a library that using twilio for sms, and nuget from that library,  now I would like to use this library in my Asp.net core web application.

I have it in the same solution and I used dependency injection

```
private IMessageSender _messageSender;

private readonly ILogger<MessageController> _logger;
public MessageController(ILogger<MessageController> logger, IMessageSender messageSender)
{
    _logger = logger;
    this._messageSender = messageSender;

}

public ActionResult Send(SmsMessage smsMessage)
{
    var viewModel = new MessageViewModel
    {
        SmsMessage = new SmsMessage(),

    };
    _messageSender.Send();
    return View("MessageStatus", viewModel);
}
```

However in this method `send()`; I can't add the `smsMessage` since its a model from  Web application and the method is requesting the model from library project so I guess my approach is completely wrong.
Can you please advise?

Comment: Are you using visual studio? If so it's just a case of right clicking the "dependecies" in the project and clicking the "Add Project Reference option" if your not here's a link to a way to do it via the cli https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference

Comment: i have done that, thank you. I am not sure if i should use the model from the library or the web application? In the question i mentioned send() method that requires model from the class library

Comment: Well the library is only going to take types that it knows about. Since your library doesn't depend on your web application (nor should it) your web application will need to use the library's types.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. I wasnt sure.

Comment: @orbitobalgin the following example will help you for the twilio sms sending in dotnet core https://rajeeshmenoth.wordpress.com/2017/12/06/sending-sms-using-asp-net-core-with-twilio-sms-api/